# Streaming all local audio to Icecast Server

Tags: audio, streaming

Does anyone know if it's possible to stream all audio on a computer to a local icecast server. I was able to stream individual files using ices2 but not all audio generated from my computer.

Any thoughts, or is there a better way to setup some way for anyone to stream my local computers audio over the internet or local network?

Answer (score 2):

Give darkice and jack should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with icecast and ices.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9280

or/and

http://beginlinux.com/server_training/8-ubuntuadmin/874-create-a-radio-station

Ignore the os type as most of config is generic. Get a working stream then play with different setups.